# While inserting (key, value) in a tree, the node doesnt form a tree structure

Tags: c, avl-tree

I am trying to create avl tree which reads (key, value) pair one by one from the file and forms the tree based on the data of the key.

First, to read the tuples into key and value and passed them to the create function where I have initialized a tree with the structure

```
typedef struct AVLTree{
    int  size;      // count of items in avl tree
    AVLTreeNode *root; // root
} AVLTree;

AVLTree *newAVLTree()
{
    AVLTree *T;
    T = malloc(sizeof (AVLTree));
    assert (T != NULL);
    T->size = 0;
    T->root = NULL;
    return T;
}
```

then i assign the value of the root of the tree which is NULL,initially, to the AVLTreeNode whose structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct AVLTreeNode {
    int key; //key of this item
    int  value;  //value (int) of this item
    int height; //height of the subtree rooted at this node
    struct AVLTreeNode *parent; //pointer to parent
    struct AVLTreeNode *left; //pointer to left child
    struct AVLTreeNode *right; //pointer to right child
} AVLTreeNode;

//data type for AVL trees
typedef struct AVLTree{
    int  size;      // count of items in avl tree
    AVLTreeNode *root; // root
} AVLTree;

// create a new AVLTreeNode
AVLTreeNode *newAVLTreeNode(int k, int v )
{
    AVLTreeNode *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(AVLTreeNode));
    assert(new != NULL);
    new->key = k;
    new->value = v;
    new->height = 0; // height of this new node is set to 0
    new->left = NULL; // this node has no child
    new->right = NULL;
    new->parent = NULL; // no parent
    return new;
}
```

Now, for every key, value pair that i read from the file, i pass it into the create function and check 3 conditions as following:

```
void insert_in_tree(int key, int value, struct AVLTreeNode **node){


    // if the tree is empty
    if(*node == NULL){
        node = newNode;
    }
    // insert on left if the data in the key is less than the data in the node.
    else if (key<(*node)->key){
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->left);
    }
    // insert on right if the data in the key is greater than the data in the node.
    else if(key>(*node)->key)
    {
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->right);
    }

}
```

PS: Dont worry about the 'value' part in the newAVLTreeNode as i'll be handling duplicates later using that.

With the above code, i expected the tree to be formed but that didnt happen. Upon further investigation and debuggin, i found that 
while insert_in_tree is passed with new key and value, the node is also new instead of the one already created.

```
AVLTree *CreateAVLTree(const char *filename)
{
    //Inititalising a new tree
    AVLTree *tree = newAVLTree();
// initialising the head to root of tree i.e. null
    AVLTreeNode *head = tree->root;
    int key, value;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r"); // open a file
    if(file == NULL) {
        return 1;                                   // error checking
    }
    while (fscanf (file, " (%d,%d)", &key, &value) == 2)  // check for number of conversions
    //  space added  here ^
    {
        insert_in_tree(key, value, &head);
        //printf("%d,%d\n", key, value);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return tree;
}
```

```
int main() //sample main for testing
{
    AVLTree *tree1;
    tree1=CreateAVLTree("File1.txt");
    //PrintAVLTree(tree1);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to be as elaborate as possible but feel free to ask me questions if you dont understand. Happy to answer.
Kindly help.
[image: Nodes are formed, but the tree is still NULL]

Comment: `node = newNode;` will not work. You need a double pointer, `struct AVLTreeNode **node`

Comment: `insert_in_tree` is recursive but on _every_ call you `malloc` a new node. That is a big memory leak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more the correction already described in the answers :

```
void insert_in_tree(int key, int value, struct AVLTreeNode **node){
    // if the tree is empty
    if(*node == NULL){
        *node = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);
    }
    // insert on left if the data in the key is less than the data in the node.
    else if (key<(*node)->key){
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->left);
    }
    // insert on right if the data in the key is greater than the data in the node.
    else if(key>(*node)->key)
    {
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->right);
    }
}
```

in *CreateAVLTree* you (now) set the tree of *node* into *head* but you missed to update `tree->root`, an easy way is to not use the temporary var *head* but to use `tree->root` directly :

```
AVLTree *CreateAVLTree(const char *filename)
{
    //Inititalising a new tree
    AVLTree *tree = newAVLTree();
    // initialising the head to root of tree i.e. null
    int key, value;
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r"); // open a file
    if(file == NULL) {
        return NULL;                                   // error checking
    }
    while (fscanf (file, " (%d,%d)", &key, &value) == 2)  // check for number of conversions
    //  space added  here ^
    {
        insert_in_tree(key, value, &tree->root);
        //printf("%d,%d\n", key, value);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return tree;
}
```

I also replaced the invalid `return 1;` by `return NULL;` when the file cannot be open.

Note the field *size* is not set, perhaps it must contains the size of the node list, in that case just add `tree->size += 1;` near the call of `insert_in_tree`

If I add definitions to print the result :

```
void PrintNodes(struct AVLTreeNode * l)
{
  if (l == NULL)
    printf("()");
  else {
    putchar('(');
    PrintNodes(l->left);
    printf(" %d %d %d ", l->key, l->value, l->height);
    PrintNodes(l->right);
    putchar(')');
  }
}

void PrintAVLTree(AVLTree * tree)
{
  printf("%d elements : ", tree->size);
  PrintNodes(tree->root);
  putchar('\n');
}
```

and put `PrintAVLTree(tree1);` out of comment in *main*, compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall t.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat File1.txt 
(2, 50) (4, 30) (9, 30) (10, 400) (-5, -40)
(7, 20) (19, 200) (20, 50) (-18, -200) (-2, 29)
(2, 67) (4, 35) (9, 45) (-18, 100)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
14 elements : (((() -18 -200 0 ()) -5 -40 0 (() -2 29 0 ())) 2 50 0 (() 4 30 0 ((() 7 20 0 ()) 9 30 0 (() 10 400 0 (() 19 200 0 (() 20 50 0 ()))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Mikhail was nearly there but didn't spot the memory leak. I correct that below:

```
void insert_in_tree(int key, int value, struct AVLTreeNode **node){
    // if the tree is empty
    if(*node == NULL){
        *node = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);
    }
    // insert on left if the data in the key is less than the data in the node.
    else if (key<(*node)->key){
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->left);
    }
    // insert on right if the data in the key is greater than the data in the node.
    else if(key>(*node)->key)
    {
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->right);
    }
}
```

As a summary of fixes:

- you needed to pass a pointer to the place where to put the newly allocated node because C passes by value. That is called a "double pointer".
- you allocated memory on every recursive call but you only needed to that once you know where to insert.

Answer (score 1):

In function `insert_in_tree` you are trying to modify parameter that was passed by value.  You need to pass is by reference like this:

```
void insert_in_tree(int key, int value, struct AVLTreeNode **node){
    // if the tree is empty
    if(*node == NULL){
        *node = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);
    }
    // insert on left if the data in the key is less than the data in the node.
    else if (key<(*node)->key){
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->left);
    }
    // insert on right if the data in the key is greater than the data in the node.
    else if(key>(*node)->key)
    {
        insert_in_tree(key,value,&(*node)->right);
    }
}
```

Also, in case `node != NULL` this function leads to a memory leak, because it allocates new node but does not save pointer to it anywhere.

BTW, what you are trying to create is not AVL tree, but rather [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

Comment: Note the memory leak as in my comment.

Comment: ...so simply do `*node = newAVLTreeNode(key, value);`

Comment: Updated the code but my Xcode editor gives an error on both the else if conditions as: "Member reference base type 'struct AVLTreeNode *' is not a structure or union".

Comment: Yeah, you need to `if(key>(*node)->key)...`

Comment: I will handle the balancing in the tree to make it avl once it is created.

Comment: the build failed on the base case with the changes suggested.

Comment: @AkhilJain of course you need to change the calls of `insert_in_tree` to give the address so `insert_in_tree(k, v, head);` must be `insert_in_tree(k, v, &head);`, did you ?

Comment: @bruno Yes, i did, but the tree is still null. Although while debugging, all the nodes are being properly formed. I think the problem is that the root of the tree is not pointing to the head. What do you think ? Added the screenshot for reference.

Comment: @AkhilJain you still have a simple error, I added an answer to solve